# Writing ॐ in latex

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, characters

I am trying to write a document in Bengali, where at a point I need to write the sanskrit letter ॐ. However, I am not able to write it yet. Here is my working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,fullpage,amsmath,amssymb,geometry,polyglossia,xltxtra}

\usepackage{devanagari}

\setmainfont{[kalpurush.ttf]}
\title{-----}
\author{----}
\date{}
\pagestyle{empty}


 \begin{document}


\maketitle
\newpage
\noindent \begin{center}\begin{huge}১.  \end{huge}\end{center}ॐ
\end{document}
```

But in output it is only showing me a box.

How can I resolve that? (By the way, I am trying to compile it via Xelatex.)

Comment: Your char is not in the font, you get a message in the log: `There is no ॐ (U+0950) in font [kalpurush].ttf`. Side remark: The devanagari package is not for xelatex.

Comment: How to do this then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With a current tex system you can run on a command line

```
albatross 0x0950
```

and

```
albatross 0x09E7
```

This will give you a list of fonts that support your characters.

I found e.g. FreeSerif which contains both, and two Noto fonts which contained one char each:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}


\setmainfont{FreeSerif}[Script=Bengali]
\newfontfamily\bengalifont{Noto Sans Bengali}[Script=Bengali]
\newfontfamily\devafont{Noto Sans Devanagari}[Script=Devanagari]

\begin{document}

১. ॐ

\bengalifont ১.
\devafont ॐ
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: "Who are you, who are so wise in the ways of [fonts]?" -apologies to Monty Python.  (and +1)

Comment: +1. A minor note: To run the `albatross` utility on one's system, Java Runtime has to be enabled. However, current MacOS systems do not enable Java and Java Runtime.